# Flask-sqlalchemy backref not working

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implementing a app using flask and sqlalchemy.

Here is my models.py

```
from blog import db
from blog import bcrypt


class Base(db.Model):

    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(256))
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref="author", lazy="dynamic")
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password=password)


    def check_password_hash(self, password):
        result = bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, password)
        if result:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"
    title = db.Column(db.String(64))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I created User object, and also create post, and they are related.
and backref is not working.

I mean that in templates.

```
{{ post.author.nickname }}
```

Result is None.
I don't know why this is not working.
user_id column, ForeignKey is working.

Comment: your script works just fine on my end. are you sure post.author is None? It would raise and exception..

Comment: Yeah... I don't know why it does not working.. my friends are all works fine.. but mine is not... do i need to re-create db?

Comment: Are you sure that the `User` object is loaded before the `session` is closed? How do you load the `post` instance from the database?

Comment: I load Post from SQLAlchemy using Post.query.filter_by(filter).first()

Comment: I think User query did not need to be loaded from session..