# Flask-SQLAlchemy - Backref isn't working, value is None

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I think I have the same issue as [here on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323644/flask-sqlalchemy-backref-not-working) Using python 3.5, flask-sqlalchemy, and sqlite. I am trying to establish a one (User) to many (Post) relationship.

```
class User(db_blog.Model):
    id = db_blog.Column(db_blog.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db_blog.Column(db_blog.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db_blog.Column(db_blog.String(120), unique=True)
    posts = db_blog.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: {0}>'.format(self.nickname)

class Post(db_blog.Model):
    id = db_blog.Column(db_blog.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db_blog.Column(db_blog.String(2500))
    title = db_blog.Column(db_blog.String(140))
    user_id = db_blog.Column(db_blog.Integer, db_blog.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __init__(self, body, title, **kwargs):
        self.body = body
        self.title = title

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Title: {0}\nPost: {1}\nAuthor: {2}>'.format(self.title, self.body, self.author)
```

Author is None.

```
>>> u = User(nickname="John Doe", email="jdoe@email.com")
>>> u
<User: John Doe>
>>> db_blog.session.add(u)
>>> db_blog.session.commit()
>>> u = User.query.get(1)
>>> u
<User: John Doe>
>>> p = Post(body="Body of post", title="Title of Post", author=u)
>>> p
<Title: Title of Post
Post: Body of post
Author: None> #Here I expect- "Author: John Doe>"
```

I get the same result after session add/commit of the post and so can't find the post author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the newly created `post` to the `posts` attribute of the user, it will work:

```
>>> u = User(nickname="John Doe", email="jdoe@email.com")
>>> u
<User: John Doe>
>>> db_blog.session.add(u)
>>> p = Post(body="Body of post", title="Title of Post")
>>> p
<Title: Title of Post
Post: Body of post
Author: None>
>>> db_blog.session.add(p)
>>> db_blog.session.commit()
>>> u.posts.append(p)
>>> p
<Title: Title of Post
Post: Body of post
Author: <User: John Doe>>
>>> p.author
<User: John Doe>
```

The reason your code doesn't work as-is, is because you've defined an `__init__` constructor for your `Post` class, and this doesn't consider the `author` field at all, so Python doesn't know what to do with that `author` parameter.

Comment: This solution works after rearranging, but doesn't answer why the original code fails. Rearranged: `u = User.query.get(1) `, `p = Post("body", "title")`,   `u.posts.append(p)`, `db_blog.session.add(p) and commit`, and the results are what I want. But I based my code on Grinberg's and others and they aren't required to append the post to the user. Their code works as in my example, by inserting the user query into the post. Ex. `author=u`. Can anyone answer why my code fails as-is before I accept? [microblog tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database)

Comment: @Cha0 I have updated my answer with further explanation

Answer (score 0):

You added your own `__init__` to `Post`. While it accepts keyword arguments, it does nothing with them. You can either update it to use them

```
def __init__(self, body, title, **kwargs):
    self.body = body 
    self.title = title
    for k, v in kwargs:
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

Or, ideally, you can just remove the method and let SQLAlchemy handle it for you.